# Android process has died after background

Tags: android

I have a chat app, that is uses one thread for the socket. 
My probleme is: after I going to background, sometimes the app is killed my the launcher in phones.

On TABLETs every background/foreground operation has a "app died, killed by launcher"

How can I solve this?

**UPDATE:**

```
   <activity android:name=".ChatStart"
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:launchMode="singleTop"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
              android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"

              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" 
              >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**How can I rewrite it as a Service? Is it an easy way to do it only in the manifest?**

thanks, Leslie

Comment: Use a service and/or a notification that keeps the service running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your app is in the background, Android may terminate it anytime it sees fit. Usually this happens when there is a need for memory, i.e. when other programs are started.

To keep Android from automatically terminating your app you need a [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html). Using a service makes it a lot less likely (but not impossible) for Android to kill your process when it needs the memory.

Comment: @Iacas You can try to and add an empty service class. Create a new class that extends Service and add it to your manifest: <service android:name=".EmptyService" ></service>. Not sure if this is enough though, you may need to start the service to prevent your app from terminating